# Is there a D3 v4 version of Collapsible Indented Tree?

Tags: d3.js

I loaded the code for the [Collapsible Indented Tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025). This uses D3 v3. Is there a D3 v4 version somewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of an indented collapsible tree using D3js V4 (I'm not using links to connects the nodes):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/psggohjv/3/)

```js
 var treeData =
     {
      "name": "Top Level",
      "parent": "null",
      "children":  [
        {
          "name": "Level 2: A",
          "parent": "Top Level",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Son of A",
              "parent": "Level 2: A",
              "children" : [
                {
                  "name": "child of Son",
                  "parent": "Son of A"
                }
              ]
            },//children
            {
              "name": "Daughter of A",
              "parent": "Level 2: A"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Level 2: B",
          "parent": "Top Level"
        }
      ]
    }

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 20},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    
    barHeight = 30,
    barWidth = width * .1;


var i = 0,
    duration = 400,
    root;


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var root = d3.hierarchy(treeData) // Constructs a root node from the specified hierarchical data.

var tree = d3.tree().nodeSize([0, 30]) //Invokes tree

function update(source) {

  // Compute the flattened node list. TODO use d3.layout.hierarchy.
   nodes = tree(root); //returns a single node with the properties of d3.tree()
   nodesSort = [];

  d3.select("svg").transition()
      .duration(duration); //transition to make svg looks smoother

  // returns all nodes and each descendant in pre-order traversal (sort)
  nodes.eachBefore(function (n) {

     nodesSort.push(n); 
  });

  // Compute the "layout".
  nodesSort.forEach(function (n,i) {
    n.x = i *barHeight;
  })


  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodesSort, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); }); //assigning id for each node

  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {  return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("y", -barHeight / 2)
      .attr("height", barHeight)
      .attr("width", barWidth)
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("dy", 3.5)
      .attr("dx", 5.5)
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.depth == 0 ? d.data.name + " >>>" : d.depth == 1 ? d.data.name + " >>" : d.data.name ; });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  nodeEnter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1);

  node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
    .select("rect")
      .style("fill", color);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

    nodes.eachBefore(function (d) {
      d.x0 = d.x;
      d.y0 = d.y
    });

}

// Initalize function
update(root);


// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

function color(d) {
  return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "lightgreen";
}
```

```css
.node rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .5;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not quite the tree you referenced but it is a collapsible tree, hopefully it helps

https://jsfiddle.net/MaryBartlett/ypgunjfw/5/

```
    var network = {
    "id": 3083,
    "title": "Some test data 3083",
    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3044,
    "cachedRAG": "G",
    "noChildren": 25,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2921,
            "title": "Some test data 2921",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 4826,
                    "title": "Some test data 4826",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 2921,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3224,
            "title": "Some test data 3224",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G"
        },
        {
            "id": 3223,
            "title": "Some test data 3223",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3852,
                    "title": "Some test data 3852",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3309,
                    "title": "Some test data 3309",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3305,
                    "title": "Some test data 3305",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3315,
                    "title": "Some test data 3315",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3311,
                    "title": "Some test data 3311",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "R"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3314,
                    "title": "Some test data 3314",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "R"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5265,
                    "title": "Some test data 5265",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3242,
                    "title": "Some test data 3242",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "R"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3317,
                    "title": "Some test data 3317",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 5928,
                            "title": "Some test data 5928",
                            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3317,
                            "cachedRAG": "G"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3398,
                    "title": "Some test data 3398",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "G",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 3477,
                            "title": "Some test data 3477",
                            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3398,
                            "cachedRAG": "R"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3239,
                    "title": "Some test data 3239",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "R"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3241,
                    "title": "Some test data 3241",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 3223,
                    "cachedRAG": "R"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3213,
            "title": "Some test data 3213",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "R"
        },
        {
            "id": 3563,
            "title": "Some test data 3563",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G"
        },
        {
            "id": 3562,
            "title": "Some test data 3562",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G"
        },
        {
            "id": 2922,
            "title": "Some test data 2922",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "R"
        },
        {
            "id": 5502,
            "title": "Some test data 5502",
            "alignedToObjectiveId": 3083,
            "cachedRAG": "G",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5514,
                    "title": "Some test data 5514",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 5502,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5523,
                    "title": "Some test data 5523",
                    "alignedToObjectiveId": 5502,
                    "cachedRAG": "G"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    i = 0,
    duration = 750;


   var ragToClass = function (status) {
        switch (status) {
        case 'U':
            return 'node--upcoming';
        case 'G':
            return 'node--green';
        case 'A':
            return 'node--amber';
        default:
            return 'node--red';
        }
    };



        var createTree;
        var connector = function (d) {
            return 'M' + d.x + ',' + d.y +
                'C' + (d.x + d.parent.x) / 2 + ',' + d.y +
                ' ' + (d.x + d.parent.x) / 2 + ',' + d.parent.y +
                ' ' + d.parent.x + ',' + d.parent.y;
        };

        var tree = d3.tree()
            .size([width, height]);

        var svg = d3.select('#network').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var root = tree(d3.hierarchy(network));

        var collapse = function (d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        };

        root.each(function (d) {
            d.name = d.title; //transferring name to a name variable
            d.id = i; //Assigning numerical Ids
            i += i;
        });

        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        root.children.forEach(collapse);

        createTree = function (source) {

            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree(root).descendants();
            var links = nodes.slice(1);
            var node;
            var nodeEnter;
            var nodeUpdate;
            var nodeExit;
            var link;
            var linkEnter;

            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            _.forEach(nodes, function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });

            // Update the nodes…
            node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
                .data(nodes, function (d) {
                    return d.id || (d.id += i);
                });

            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
                .attr('class', 'node')
                .attr('transform', function () {
                    return 'translate(' + source.x0 + ',' + source.y0 + ')';
                })
                .on('click', function (d) {
                    if (d.children) {
                        d._children = d.children;
                        d.children = null;
                    } else {
                        d.children = d._children;
                        d._children = null;
                    }
                    createTree(d);

                });

            nodeEnter.append('circle')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .attr('class', function (d) {
                    return ragToClass(d.data.cachedRAG);
                });

            nodeEnter.append('text')
                .attr('dy', '.35em')
                .attr('y', function (d) {
                    return d.children ? -20 : 20;
                })
                .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.data.title;
                });

            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            nodeUpdate = node.merge(nodeEnter).transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('transform', function (d) {
                    return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
                });

            nodeUpdate.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .attr('class', function (d) {
                    return ragToClass(d.data.cachedRAG);
                });

            nodeUpdate.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('transform', function () {
                    return 'translate(' + source.x + ',' + source.y + ')';
                })
                .remove();

            nodeExit.select('circle')
                .attr('r', 10)
                .attr('class', function (d) {
                    return ragToClass(d.data.cachedRAG);
                });

            nodeExit.select('text')
                .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);


            // Update the links…
            link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
                .data(links, function (l) {
                    var id = l.id + '->' + l.parent.id;
                    return id;
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', connector);

            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', 'g')
                .attr('class', 'link')
                .attr('d', function () {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0, parent: {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}};
                    return connector(o);
                });

            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.merge(linkEnter).transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', connector);

            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .attr('d', function () {
                    var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y, parent: {x: source.x, y: source.y}};
                    return connector(o);
                })
                .remove();

            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        };
        createTree(root);
```